# ¿Qué significa el >> y << en Go?

Tags: go

Estoy aprendiendo `Go` ([golang](https://golang.org/)) y me topé con que no entiendo esta sintaxis en la declaración de variables o constantes. Por ejemplo:

```
const (
    Big   = 1 << 100
    Small = Big >> 99
)
```

¿Qué significa exactamente esto?

Comment: Un poco tarde pero he agregado otra respuesta para complementar información, con 2 ejemplos en GO.

Comment: Me parece genial @Elenasys, este tipo de información es bastante útil cuando otras personas tienen la misma duda y llegan acá.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Los operadores `<<` y `>>` son operadores de desplazamiento de bit y sólo se pueden aplicar a números enteros:

- `<<` añadiría tantos bit (con valor 0) a la derecha del número como se indique en el valor que viene trás el operador. O lo que es lo mismo: todos los bits del número se desplazarían a la izquierda tantas posición como se especifique.

  Y como una imagen vale más que mil palabras, aquí dejo una explicación gráfica creada por CBurnett (fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_a_nivel_de_bits#Desplazamiento_l.C3.B3gico))

  [image: Imagen de la Wikipedia creada por Cburnett]
- `>>` eliminaría tantos bits a la derecha del número como se indique en el valor que viene detrás del operador. O lo que es lo mismo: los bits del número se desplazarían a la derecha tantas posiciones como se especifique (truncándose igual número de veces).

  Otra explicación gráfica creada por Cburnett (fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_a_nivel_de_bits#Desplazamiento_l.C3.B3gico))

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según la [documentación de Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) sobre operadores aritméticos:

> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count specified by the right operand. They implement arithmetic shifts if the left operand is a signed integer and logical shifts if it is an unsigned integer. There is no upper limit on the shift count. Shifts behave as if the left operand is shifted n times by 1 for a shift count of n. As a result, x << 1 is the same as x*2 and x >> 1 is the same as x/2 but truncated towards negative infinity.

Y la traducción al español (algo libre, espero que se entienda):

> Los operadores de desplazamiento desplazan el operando de la izquierda tantas veces como se indique en el operando de la derecha. Implementan desplazamiento aritmético si el operando de la izquierda es un entero con signo, y desplazamiento lógico si es un entero sin signo. No hay límite en cuanto al valor de desplazamientos a realizar. Los desplazamientos se comportan como si el operando de la izquierda es desplazado n veces por 1 por cada desplazamiento de n. Como resultado, x << 1 es lo mismo que x*2 y x >> 1 es lo mismo que x/2 pero truncado hasta el infinito negativo.

---

Esa última parte es muy importante porque permite crear una fórmula que seguro ayuda a entender mejor qué es lo que hacen:

- El operador `n << m` es equivalente a "n multiplicado por 2, m veces" = **n * 2<sup>m</sup>**.
- El operador `n >> m` es equivalente a "n dividido por 2, m veces" = **n * 2<sup>-m</sup>**.

---

Así, en el caso que pones de ejemplo:

- `Big` = 1 * 2<sup>100</sup> = 1.267.650.600.228.229.401.496.703.205.376 (desborda los enteros).
- `Small` = `Big` * 2<sup>-99</sup> = 2<sup>100</sup> * 2<sup>-99</sup> = 2<sup>1</sup> = 2.

Comment: me imaginaba que seria similar a otros lenguajes pero por curiosidad entre, buena explicacion. Saludos.

Comment: por otro lado, igual se podria poner algo asi para aclarar que los bit se pierden si por ejemplo : Los bit que salen del registro por un extremo se pierden y en el otro extremo del registro se rellena con un bit cero por cada bit desplazado.
ej: Si se tiene en un registro de 8 bits el valor 10110011, y se hace un desplazamiento hacia la izquierda de un bit todos los bits se mueven una posición hacia la izquierda, el bit de la izq. se pierde y entra un bit cero de relleno por el lado derecho. (hacia la der. ocurre algo parecido), el bit de la der. se pierde, el de la izq. se rellena con un 0

Comment: Efectivamente, la idea es similar al resto de lenguajes de programación. Aunque no sé si lo expliqué de la mejor manera

Comment: a mi personalmente, creo que si, ademas del detalle de poner -> Big = 1 * 2100 .... pues sin esa aclaracion puede parecer en algun caso que se crea que  Big   = 1 << 100 lo que hace es poner algo asi 100 en Big, a nivel de entero, por eso creo que el ejemplo deja mas claro que es a nivel de bit (cada bit 2 estados), Saludos

Answer (score 6):

Los operadores **<<** y **>>** están definidos como [operadores aritméticos dentro del lenguaje GO](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) , se definen como operadores de desplazamiento de bit:

- **<< operador de desplazamiento de bit a la izquierda.**
- **>> operador de desplazamiento de bit a la derecha.**

Antes de comenzar a explicar como funcionan los operadores e desplazamiento bit a bit, recordemos como obtenemos un valor decimal a partir de un número binario.

por ejemplo ¿cual seria el valor de `1011 0011` en decimal? Bien, de acuerdo a su posición de derecha a izquierda tenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, `1011 0011` es igual a `179` en decimal

Es muy importante comentar que este operador existe en otros lenguajes ademas de GO, como son: `Java`, `php`, `C`, `C#`, etc

Un ejemplo sencillo para explicar como funciona el operador de desplazamiento de bit a la izquierda sería:

`3 << 2` cuyo valor resulta ser `12`, la explicación es:

`3` en binario es `0011` la operación indica un desplazamiento de bit en 2 posiciones hacia la izquierda, por lo tanto:
`1100` que en binario resulta ser `12`

Si realizamos la operación inversa:

`12 >> 2` cuyo resultado es `3`;
`12` en binario es `1100`, si realizamos el desplazamiento de bits hacia la derecha 2 posiciones, obtenemos `0011` que en decimal es `3`.

Este es un ejemplo en [lenguaje Go](https://golang.org/) donde puedes ver como a partir del valor `1` (Valor en binario: `0001`) al realizar un desplazamiento de bits hacia la izquierda, su valor va cambiando:

```
package main    
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var t , i uint
    t , i = 1 , 1

    for i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d << %d = %d \n", t , i , t<<i)
    }    
}
```

esta sería la salida:

```
1 << 1 = 2     (Valor en binario: 0010) 
1 << 2 = 4     (Valor en binario: 0100)
1 << 3 = 8     (Valor en binario: 1000) 
1 << 4 = 16    (Valor en binario: 1 0000) 
1 << 5 = 32    (Valor en binario: 10 0000) 
1 << 6 = 64    (Valor en binario: 100 0000) 
1 << 7 = 128   (Valor en binario: 1000 0000)
1 << 8 = 256   (Valor en binario: 1 0000 0000) 
1 << 9  = 512  (Valor en binario: 10 0000 0000)
```

Ahora un ejemplo en [lenguaje Go](https://golang.org/) efectuando el corrimiento de bits hacia la derecha:

```
package main    
import "fmt"

func main() {

    var t , i uint
    t , i = 1024 , 1

    for i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d >> %d = %d \n", t , i , t>>i)
    }    
}
```

Salida:

```
1024 >> 1 = 512  (Valor en binario: 10 0000 0000)
1024 >> 2 = 256  (Valor en binario: 1 0000 0000) 
1024 >> 3 = 128  (Valor en binario: 1000 0000)
1024 >> 4 = 64   (Valor en binario: 100 0000) 
1024 >> 5 = 32   (Valor en binario: 10 0000) 
1024 >> 6 = 16   (Valor en binario: 1 0000) 
1024 >> 7 = 8    (Valor en binario: 1000) 
1024 >> 8 = 4    (Valor en binario: 0100)
1024 >> 9 = 2    (Valor en binario: 0010)
```

Más información:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators